# How to create a mixin for advanced enum and use it in a generic widget?

Tags: dart, generics, enums

My goal is to write a generic `Widget` that, in this case, enables the user for selecting an `enum` value among all the values from the enum.

So I'd like to write something like so:

```dart
class WheelPickerWidget<T extends Enum> extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The initial value
  final T? value;

  /// The onChanged callback
  final void Function(T)? onChanged;

  /// Retuns the wheel enum picker
  const WheelPickerWidget(
      {super.key, required this.value, required this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListWheelScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemExtent: 50,
        diameterRatio: 0.6,
        //offAxisFraction: -0.4,
        squeeze: 1.8,
        //useMagnifier: true,
        //overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.8,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => onChanged?.call(T.fromValue(value)),
        children: T.values.map((c) => Text("$c")).toList());
  }
}
```

But I see `T.fromValues()` and `T.values` are generating errors as follows:

> The method 'fromValue' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromValue'.

> The getter 'values' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'values', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'values'.

I usually write my `enum`s as follows:

```dart
/// Theme to use for the app
enum AppTheme {
  green(0),
  yellow(1),
  nightBlue(2);

  const AppTheme(this.value);
  final int value;

  factory AppTheme.fromValue(int v) => values.firstWhere((x) => x.value == v,
      orElse: () => throw Exception("Unknown value $v"));

  /// Returns the name corresponding to the enum
  @override
  String toString() {
    switch (this) {
      case green:
        return i18n_Green.i18n;
      case yellow:
        return i18n_Yellow.i18n;
      case nightBlue:
        return i18n_Night_blue.i18n;
    }
  }
}
```

Where I make `fromValue()` readily available.

And I guess I could use `mixin` to create a specific form of `enum` that complies to the requirements.

```dart
/// Advanced enum
mixin EnumMixin {
}
```

But I didn't manage to do it: one reason is the factory cannot be supported by the mixin.

So to sum up, my questions are:

1. How to make my wheel picker class works with my enum?;
2. How to create a generic way (possibly being a mixin) to conform all my enums to a way it can be supported by my generic wheel picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make `T.someConstructor()` or `T.someStaticMethod()` work for some generic type `T`.  Dart does not consider constructors and `static` methods to be part of the class interface, and they are not inherited.

In general, whenever you want to use something like `T.someConstructor()` or `T.someStaticMethod()`, you're probably better off using a callback instead.  Similarly, instead of using `T.values`, you can accept a `List<T>` argument.

For example:

```dart
class WheelPickerWidget<T extends Enum> extends StatelessWidget {
  WheelPickerWidget({required this.values, required this.fromValue});

  final List<T> values;
  final T Function(int) fromValue;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListWheelScrollView(
        ...
        onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => onChanged?.call(fromValue(value)),
        children: values.map((c) => Text("$c")).toList());
  }
}
```

and then callers would use:

```dart
WheelPickerWidget(values: AppTheme.values, fromValue: AppTheme.fromValue);
```

Note that `fromValue` is a bit redundant in principle if you already have `values`; you could just iterate over `values` to find the `Enum` you want.  For example, you could do:

```dart
abstract class HasValue<T> {
  T get value;
}

enum AppTheme implements HasValue<int> {
  green(0),
  yellow(1),
  nightBlue(2);

  const AppTheme(this.value);

  @override
  final int value;

  ...
}

class WheelPickerWidget<T extends Enum> extends StatelessWidget {
  WheelPickerWidget({required this.values})

  final List<T> values;

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListWheelScrollView(
        ...
        onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => onChanged?.call(values.findValue(value)),
        children: values.map((c) => Text("$c")).toList());
  }
}

extension<T extends Enum> on List<T> {
  T findValue<U>(U value) {
    for (Object e in this) {
      if (e is HasValue<U> && e.value == value) {
        return e as T;
      }
    }
    throw Exception("Unknown value $value");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `findValue` is slightly awkward because there doesn't seem to be a good way to enforce that `T` derives from both `Enum` and `HasValue`, so it must perform runtime type-checking.  Additionally, [Dart will not perform automatic type promotion between unrelated types](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2047#issuecomment-782602222) (in this case, `Enum` and `HasValue`), so `findValue` upcasts to `Object` first as a workaround.

If you don't want callers to pass extra arguments, one alternative would be to store those arguments in a global lookup table with the generic type as the key.  This isn't a great general approach since a `Map<Type, ...>` depends on exact `Type` matches, so looking up a subtype wouldn't match a supertype in the `Map`.  However, `Enum`s are not allowed to be extended nor implemented, so that is not a concern.  I would consider it to be less robust, however, since it would require extra work to initialize such a `Map`, and there's no way at compile-time that it's been initialized with all of the types you care about.  As an example of how this could look:

```dart
final _fromValueMap = <Type, Enum Function(int)>{
  AppTheme: AppTheme.fromValue,
};

final _lookupValuesMap = <Type, List<Enum>>{
  AppTheme: AppTheme.values,
};

T fromValue<T>(int value) => _fromValueMap[T]!(value) as T;

List<T> lookupValues<T>() => _lookupValuesMap[T]! as List<T>;

class WheelPickerWidget<T extends Enum> extends StatelessWidget {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListWheelScrollView(
        ...
        onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => onChanged?.call(fromValue<T>(value)),
        children: lookupValues<T>().map((c) => Text("$c")).toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but does not really answer the questions. Passing arguments is my fallback so far.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca The answer to "How to make my wheel picker class works with my enum?" and "How to create a generic way ... to conform all my enums to a way it can be supported by my generic wheel picker?" is to pass your `Enum`'s values as an argument.  This does not answer "How to create a mixin for advanced enum and use it in a generic widget?" because that can't be done.  Static methods in Dart are never inherited; it is impossible for `T.someConstructor()` or `T.someStaticMethod()` to ever work in a generic.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca I've updated my answer to include an alternative approach that avoids passing extra arguments (although I still would recommend passing extra arguments instead).